# Sending JSON to PHP from Actionscript 3

Tags: php, json, actionscript-3

This html code works to do what I want ie send 'abc_request' with JSON key 1234567. (btw I changed the key):

```
<form action="index.php" method="post"><textarea name="abc_request" class="form-control" >{"key":"1234567"}</textarea><button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">POST</button></form>
```

How do I do that with Actionscript3;

So:
I am using var urlLoader:URLLoader;
I have urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST; working 
it is sending a request to the correct .php page
I just can't get the correct data format:
Best result I can get is using this:

```
var urlLoader:URLLoader;
var urlVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
urlVariables.abc_request = {"key":"1234567"};
var url:String = "index.php";
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
urlRequest.data =urlVariables;
urlLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

This is giving me a HTTPStatusEvent of 200 and 
a Bad Request echo from the php page meaning that it is receiving 'abc_request' but no key.

Any help appreciated.

Tommy Banana

By the way below

I also TRIED:

```
var abc_request:Object = {"key":"1234567"};
var jsonString:String = JSON.stringify(abc_request);
urlRequest.data = jsonString;
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

AND

```
var abc_request:Object = {"abc_request::{"key":"1234567"}};
var jsonString:String = JSON.stringify(abc_request);
urlRequest.data = jsonString;
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
urlRequest.data =urlVariables;
urlVariables.abc_request = {"key":"1234567"};
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

THEN TRIED:

```
var keyDEF:Object ={"key":"1234567"}
var jsonKey:String = JSON.stringify(keyDEF);
urlRequest.data =urlVariables;
urlVariables.abc_request = jsonKey;
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
```

Tried all these; get either a No Request reply (meaning abc_request not submitted) or a bad request ( meaning after 'abc_request is received not receiving a key.

Comment: The first script, but you need to send **String** instead of **Object**, in a direct way: **urlVariables.abc_request = '{"key":"1234567"}';** or via **JSON** conversion: **urlVariables.abc_request = JSON.stringify({"key":"1234567"});**

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Using urlVariables.abc_request = '{"key":"1234567"}'; ie adding single quotes -  stops me from getting anything back from the PHP, when I take them back out I get an HTTPStatus of 200 AND an EventCompleteHandler firing. With them in I just get status + 200. With urlVariables.abc_request = JSON.stringify({"key":"1234567"});it is the same - just status 200 but no EventCompleteHandler.

Comment: Hmmm... Probably also **urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;** rather than **TEXT**. Not sure about COMPLETE event, how it is even possible to get a 200 OK status without a proper COMPLETE? Try subscribing for all possible error events, maybe?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES doesn't seem to change the outcome. I can see when Event compete Handler fires and I can definitely get 200 Status when Event Handler doesn't fire - in cases as above when it doesn't work. Can you explain about "try subscribing for all possible error events"? Best Tommy Banana

Comment: Open the official Adobe documentation on **URLLoader**. There's a list of properties, methods and **events** you can subscribe to. COMPLETE and HTTP STATUS aside, there are error events. If you subscribe to them, you could possibly get more info about life of your requests.

Comment: hey @user12990265 do you *have* to use only AS3? if this program is always running in the browser, you can use [ExternalInterface](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to execute javascript from the swf.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Will try both of these ideas and get back.

Answer (score 0):

SO I finally got it all working:

Here is the code that works:

AS3

```
//the URLLoader
var urlLoader:URLLoader;

//holds the variables to send to PHP
var urlVariables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();

// create JSON String


 var jsonString:String = JSON.stringify({"key":"1234567"});


//let's add some variables to send to PHP

urlVariables.abc_request = jsonString;




//holds the url address

var url:String = "http://ourserver/local/rest/index.php";

//holds a URLRequest
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

//specify post as the method to send
urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

//set the variables to be used for the data to send
urlRequest.data =urlVariables;


//initialize the urlLoader
urlLoader = new URLLoader();

//specify to use variables as the data format
urlLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;


//make the actual request to the php page now
urlLoader.load(urlRequest);

//setup listeners for handling the onComplete and error handlers
urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onCompleteHandler);
urlLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onErrorHandler);
urlLoader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler);


function onCompleteHandler(e:Event):void {

            var arrayReceived:Object = JSON.parse(e.target.data);
           result2_txt.text = "did this 8" + e.target.data;
           result2_txt.appendText(arrayReceived.toString());
        }
```

and the php ended up with this:

```
echo json_encode($ourdataarray);
```

hope that helps if anyone is looking. Thanks for all the suggestions!